# PHP file_get_contents not showing url link

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with php file_get_content(), I have a txt file with links where I created a foreach loop that display multiple links in the same webpage but it's not working, please take a look at the code:

```
<?php
    $urls = file("links.txt");
    foreach($urls as $url) {
       file_get_contents($url);
       echo $url; 
    }
```

The content of links.txt is: https://www.google.com

Result: Only a String displaying "https://www.google.com"

Another code that works is :

```
$url1 = file_get_contents('https://google.com');
echo $url1;
```

This code returns google's homepage, but I need to use first method with loops to provide multiple links.

Any idea?

Comment: What if you just combine those? Assign the result of file_get_contents($url) into a new variable - then output it?

Comment: if I put $urls = file_get_contents("links.txt"); It will throw an error as a string is given instead of array

Comment: `$urls` right now is the array content of `links.txt`, assign the output of `file_get contents` to a different variable like : `$contents = file_get_contents($url); echo $contents;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of combining the things you already had implemented:

```
$urls = file("links.txt");
foreach($urls as $url) {
  $contents = file_get_contents($url);
  echo $contents; 
}
```

Both `file` and `file_get_contents` are functions that return some value; what you had to do is putting return value of the latter one inside a variable, then outputting that variable with `echo`.

In fact, you didn't even need to use variable: this...

```
$urls = file("links.txt");
foreach($urls as $url) {
  echo file_get_contents($url);
}
```

... should have been sufficient too.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine with 1 link (google) but once I add a second link (yahoo) I get errors: 
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com ): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 


Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.yahoo.com ): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Comment: Those are different errors caused by the links themselves being incorrect, therefore I'd strongly suggest var_dumping those $urls to see what's the issue with them - in a separate question. As this particularly question is solved, you may close it by accepting that answer.

Comment: You'll see a checking mark with 'Accept this answer...' tooltip right behind the voting buttons, to the left of the answer. Also I'd suggest checking [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it's really wrapping up the functionality of the site in a nice package.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work